# @types/eslint Error: ChainExpression and ImportExpression members of ESTree not exported

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, eslint, tsconfig

I am having some troubles after executing my angular application with `npm start`, 'ChainExpression' & 'ImportExpression'members of ESTree interface are not exported causing errors...

Please check image below:

[image]

I am using `Angular 12` and next node dependencies in my package.json, please see below:

```
{
...
"@types/node": "12.11.1",
"eslint": "7.10.0",
"ts-node": "8.3.0",
"tslib": "2.2.0",
"tslint": "6.1.0",
"typescript": "4.2.4",
...
}
```

Do you have any idea about this problem? I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem and could see there was a problem with my node modules @types:
eslint was referring to ChainExpression and ImportExpression which were missing from  estree.  compared these with a new angular12 project and then fixed by updating my estree like so:

```
npm install @types/estree@0.0.47
```

Comment: Thanx! This helped me (with latest version though (0.0.50))

Comment: I was having a similar issue where a depenency of ng-packagr was using @types/estree@0.0.39 and for whatever reason, this causing issues when trying to use ng serve

Comment: Also had the same issue using ng-packagr. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Also had the same issue using `@storybook/addon-docs`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanx! helped to fix same problem in nestjs project. Fixed.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem running typedoc.

This fixed it.

```
npm install @types/estree@latest
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.
led me to adding `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]` to `tsconfig.json` which solved it.

```
$ node -v
v16.13.0

$ npm -v
8.5.1

$ yarn -v
1.22.5
```

Comment: Thanx! helped to fix same problem

Comment: the default seems better in my case, 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots
I had the below problem, NX used `@types/estree@0.0.39`

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. (Node v12.22.0)

Comment: Thanks, this has solved my issue and should be marked as answer instead of adding a new dependency in the project.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on angular migration. I'm migrated my project from angular 11 to angular 12. while building the project I started getting following error

```
StaticBlock?: ((node: ESTree.StaticBlock & NodeParentExtension) => void) | undefined;
```

As suggested above I downgraded to @types/estree@0.0.47. I started getting more errors.

```
PropertyDefinition?: ((node: ESTree.PropertyDefinition & NodeParentExtension) => void) | undefined;

PrivateIdentifier?: ((node: ESTree.PrivateIdentifier & NodeParentExtension) => void) | undefined;

 StaticBlock?: ((node: ESTree.StaticBlock & NodeParentExtension) => void) | undefined;
```

I digged into definition file realized these properties were not available in @types/estree definition file.

I upgraded estree from 0.0.47 to 1.0.0. This **resolved** build error.

```
npm i -D @types/estree@1.0.0
```

Comment: Exactly my issue, this worked ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try updating `eslint` to version `7.27.0`, delete `package-lock.json`, delete `node_modules` folder and then `npm install` again.

It seems `@types/estree` updated 14 hours ago [looking here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/estree) and this could be causing issues.

By the way, if you are using `eslint` for linting, you can get rid of `tslint` entry in package.json.

Comment: Ok, try creating a new Angular 12 project and try to copy its dependencies as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow @types/eslint is behind. Solution to this problem is:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/eslint
```

Then **remove** *package-lock.json* and *node_modules* folder and run install again:

```
npm install
```

Errors should be gone now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by upgrading angular-eslint-schematics to compatible version for Angular 12 which is "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.7.0".

I want to write it down here since it does not requires adding new library to project.